# Dialogflow Intents Follow-ups not under right intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

For example if you have IntentA and you add 2 followup intents: IntentB, IntentC, it works ok it should add a context because it doesn't have an output context yet. But here is the problem. Sometimes if you add another one, for example a FallbackIntent, it just adds another context (SOMETIMES) and if you delete it in both(IntentA and FallbackIntent), so they both have the same context, meaning they should still be connected, and the hiearchy shouldn't change,but it still does. It still works perfectly, but still this is a wierd behavior. Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

[image: Hierarchy]

Intent A

[image: IntentA]

Intent B

[image: IntentB]

Fallback

[image: Fallback]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to resolve this issue and organize the structure of your dialogflow agent is to upload the intents using `create_intent()` function of dialogflow api.
You can give the root intent as `parent_followup_intent_name`, and all the intents having this **root intent** will fall under same intent. Note that you will need to give root intent **ID** not the name.

You can read more about [create_intent api using python sdk](https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#managing-intents).

```
intents_client = dialogflow.IntentsClient()
intent = dialogflow.types.Intent(
        display_name=display_name,
        training_phrases=training_phrases_parts,
        messages=response,
        input_context_names=input_contexts,
        output_contexts = output_context_list,
        parent_followup_intent_name=root_intent,
)
intents_client.create_intent(parent, intent)
```

**EDIT:**
As requested, here's 2nd and easier way of doing this without any prograpping knowledge.

- Suppose your agent looks like below screenshot before, and you want
  to group intents under `how to solve` intent

[image: agent_before_grouping]

- Go to **Setting** -> **Export and Import** -> **Export as zip** the agent

Once exported, unzip the files and go to intents folder. Your files will look something like below screenshot
[image: intent_directory_structure]

- Open `how to solve.json` file and copy the id of this intent
- Open all the json files which you want to group under `how to solve`
  intent (note we have to open the files which do not have
  `_usersays_en` as they only contain user utterances
- Paste the id of `how to solve` intent as `parentId` in these json
  files like below screenshot (in this case intent id of `how to solve` intent was `b2131b0e-f86d-429d-957c-65c070ddd5df`)

[image: parentId]

- Once all the changes have been made, then zip the directory
- Again go to **Setting** -> **Export and Import** -> **Restore from
  zip** and select the zip file you have just created
- Intent will look like below screenshot once the process is complete

[image: after_change_intent]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't use followup intents, so haven't tried this, but can you download the zip file, extract it, edit the json files, and upload the zip without using the API? (And it sounds like its just visual - it works correctly, right?)

Comment: @Prisoner yeah its just visual, there is absolutely no impact on intent matching. but its better to organize in this way (in my opinion).

Comment: Now I want to just do this even for non-followup intents. {:

Comment: @Prisoner i do this to keep same kind of intents together :)

Comment: @WinterChilly i've updated the answer with another way

Answer (score 0):

@sid8491 - this is absolutely ingenious :)
Thanks for that! Works like a charm and I can confirm that this is just a visual representation. No need to worry about changing your code.

Just a small addition: When you already have follow-up intents, they already carry

```
"id": "70a48f63-662b-48d4-9a78-dd0af3e0db87",
"parentId": "5a1b5861-fadc-480e-b03b-11bc034df8b9",
"rootParentId": "6c9cb1d6-3efb-4bac-b768-ae3265faa7b6",
```

Make sure to adjust `rootParentId` to the aforementioned `id` of the root-intent, leave parentId intact and you're all set. Didn't try with a follow-up/follow-up/follow-up etc. structure but I'd say it will follow the same pattern somehow.